# System cannot fine mysqldump although the path in specified

Tags: java, mysql

This is my code for taking a backup from my database. It obtains the path to `mysqldump.exe` using the mysql global vars. The query `SELECT @@basedir;` is returning `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\`, to which I add `bin` folder. It's the right path for `mysqldump`. But it says `The system cannot find the file specified`...!

```
    public static void backup() {
        try {
            String path = s.createSQLQuery("SELECT @@basedir;").uniqueResult() + "\\bin\\";
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    "mysqldump -u root -p xxxx aadata > c:\\dump.sql",
                    null,
                    new File(path));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerGate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Here is the error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysqldump" (in directory "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
at aaserver.ServerGate$DataPipe.backup(ServerGate.java:1631)
at aaclient.main.settings.BackupSettingsPanel.backupNowActionPerformed(BackupSettingsPanel.java:145)
at aaclient.main.settings.BackupSettingsPanel.access$200(BackupSettingsPanel.java:26)
at aaclient.main.settings.BackupSettingsPanel$3.actionPerformed(BackupSettingsPanel.java:74)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 42 more
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem here is that each argument you pass to the command should be a separate String element. Ex:

```
    String[] command = new String[] {
    "mysqldump", 
   "-u"
    ...
    }
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work.. The problem is that it cannot "find" the file...